# 404 page for UI-Router Extras and future states when a state is not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular and as I'm usually building quite big applications I started creating a lazy loaded navigation. Things work pretty well, I'm able to lazy load modules and states using AngularUI Router, UI-Router Extras and ocLazyLoad.

Here is a simplified version of my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/BXyvzy?p=info.

My only problem is defining a 404 page with Futures States of UI-Router Extras. When I'm trying to request a state that doesn't exist or is not on any future state, the application silently redirects to "/". As far as I can see the code responsible for this in the source is:

```
function otherwiseFunc($state) {
    $log.debug("Unable to map " + $location.path());
    $location.url("/");
}];
```

This function is called as part of another function `futureState_otherwise`, which is declared as otherwise function for `$urlRouterProvider`.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(futureState_otherwise);
```

How can I handle correctly a state not found with UI-Router Extras and future states? Should I rewrite a new function for `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` or is there any better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bug in UI-Router Extras, sorry about that.  I meant to go back and hook up the stock $urlRouterProvider.otherwise declaration, but never got around to it.  You can follow https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/39 to be notified when I fix this, but that doesn't help you with your immediate problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll follow the Github issue and I'll update this question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a pull-request on ui-router-extras Github page proposing a solution and it has been merged to the project. So this problem will be fixed with the new release.

https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/pull/77

Comment: This came up in the reviews, not sure if I should flag or upvote... But if this is the answer, good job!

Comment: Yes, this feature is now working in ui-router-extras 0.0.11 and above.